# UITextField number values into NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a program with user able to type in float number into the UITextField and store it into array. Can someone kindly provide me the coding or guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly take a class level array and  initialize it in viewDidLoad and then add float value on any button action like this.....

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];// define your capacity over here.

-(IBAction)addValue
{
    [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[yourTxtFld.text floatValue]]];
}
```

Comment: why you are not try array with capacity method

Comment: There is an error it said No known class method for selector "numberWithFloat"

Comment: Its working fine at my end may be your are missing something over there

Comment: I'm not able to declare the NSMutableArray outside the IBAction function. is there anyway can be declare outside because this is not a constant variable

Comment: What you mean by constant? When you enter any value it will store in array and find it out later.

Comment: I cannot declare the NSMutableArray outside the function is there anyway I can do it

Comment: If you don't want globally. it'll work like local variable and in every case you need to initliaze it.

Comment: I want it to be global but it's didn't allow me to do soon. It's showing me error

Comment: Where you created it and where you intialized?

Comment: I intial it at the implementation .m outside the local variable